# Python equivalent of MATLAB knnimpute with 'seuclidean' distance

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, knn, imputation

I am converting some MATLAB code to python and one of the lines is

```
filled_data = knnimpute(data,1, 'distance','seuclidean')
```

I tried using `sklearn.impute.KNNImputer` but it only takes `'nan_euclidean'` as a pre-defined `metric` otherwise we have to define our own callable metric and pass that as an argument. Scipy `interpolate` has a lot of options and I got confused looking at the documentation.

What is the best way to convert the above MATLAB line into Python?

Comment: You are on the right track using ``sklearn.impute``.KNNImputer for the task. 

To use the ``seuclidean`` distance metric in KNNImputer, you can use the pairwise_distances function from sklearn.metrics to create a callable distance metric.

Comment: import numpy as np
    from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
    from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
    # Define the seuclidean distance function
    def seuclidean_distances(X, Y, V=None):
        if V is None:
            V = np.var(np.vstack([X, Y]), axis=0, ddof=1)
        return pairwise_distances(X, Y, metric='seuclidean', V=V)

Comment: # Create your input data (replace this with your actual data)
    data = np.array([
        [1, 2, np.nan],
        [3, 4, 6],
        [np.nan, 6, 8]
    ]) 
    # Instantiate the KNNImputer with the custom metric
    imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=1, metric=seuclidean_distances)   # Perform the imputation
    filled_data = imputer.fit_transform(data)
    
    print(filled_data)